# Combining multiple conditional expressions in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, unicode, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I utf-8 encode characters like **\u2013** before inserting them into SQLite.

When I pull them out with a SELECT, they are back in their unencoded form, so I need to re-encode them if I want to do anything with them. In this case, I want to write the rows to a CSV.Before writing the rows to CSV, I want to first add hyperlink to any row whose value starts with 'http'. Some values will be ints, dates etc, so I do the folliowing *conditional expression - list comprehension* combo:

```
row = ['=HYPERLINK("%s")' % cell if 'http' in str(cell) else cell for cell in row].
```

The `str()` operation then results in the well-known:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in
>   position 15: ordinal not in range(128) error.

What I need then is to perform the `.encode('utf-8')` encoding again, but only on those elements in the lists that are strings to begin with. The following won't work (since not all elements are strings):

```
['=HYPERLINK("%s")' % cell if 'http' in str(cell).encode('utf8') else cell.encode('utf8') for cell in row]
```

**TLDR:** How do I expand /modify the list comprehension to only encode an element if it's a string?

Comment: "I utf-8 encode characters like \u2013 before inserting them into SQLite." Don't; that's a silly thing to do because SQLite happily stores Unicode. If you must do a conversion do it as close to the output as you can.

Answer (score 1):

In general, work in terms of unicode as long as possible, and encoded unicode to
bytes (i.e. `str`s) only when necessary, such as writing output to a network
socket or file.

Do not mix `str`s with `unicode` -- although this is permitted in Python2, 
it causes Python2 to implicitly convert `str` to `unicode` or vice versa as necessary using the `ascii` codec. If the implicit encoding or decoding fails, then you get a UnicodeEncodingError  or UnicodedDecodingError, respectively, such as the one you are seeing.

Since `cell` is unicode, use `u'=HYPERLINK("{}")'.format(cell)` or `u'=HYPERLINK("%s")' % cell` instead of `'=HYPERLINK("%s")' % cell`. (Note that you may want to url-encode `cell` in case `cell` contains a double quote).

```
row = [u'=HYPERLINK("{}")'.format(cell) 
       if isinstance(cell, unicode) and cell.startswith(u'http') else cell 
       for cell in row]
```

Later, when/if you need to convert `row` to `str`s, you could use

```
row = [cell.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(cell, unicode) else str(cell) 
       for cell in row]
```

---

Alternatively, convert everything in `row` to `str`s first:

```
row = [cell.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(cell, unicode) else str(cell) 
       for cell in row]
```

and then you could use

```
row = ['=HYPERLINK("{}")'.format(cell) if cell.startswith('http') else cell 
       for cell in row]
```

---

Similarly, since `row` contains `cell`s which are unicode, perform the test

```
if u'http' in cell
```

using the `unicode` `u'http'` instead of the `str` `'http'`, or better yet,

```
if isinstance(cell, unicode) and cell.startswith(u'http')
```

Although no error arises if you keep `'http'` here (since the `ascii` codec can decode bytes in the 0-127 range), it is a good practice to use `u'http'` anyway since conforms to the rule never mix `str` and `unicode`, and supports mental clarity.

Comment: Thanks. But won't `if cell.startswith(u'http')` fall over when it reaches a cell that is an `int` (with a SyntaxError, since `startswith` is not a method of `int`)?

Comment: Not sure how you expected the code to work since `'http' in cell` would raise a TypeError if `cell` were an int....

Comment: I was checking for 'http' in `str(cell)` (not `cell`), and since the `str()` operation accepts an `int`, this was working fine .... until I encountered the non-ASCII character in question.

Comment: I've gotten the following to work: `[u'=HYPERLINK("{}")'.format(cell) if (isinstance(cell, basestring) and 'http' in cell.encode('utf8')) else cell
       for cell in row]`. Your verdict?

Comment: That looks okay, but upon further consideration, I think converting everything to `str` *first* might make the code look a bit prettier. You could then drop the `isinstance(cell, unicode)` check.

Comment: Seems to work, now stuck with somewhat of an inverse problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35530524/1389110